# Insert image and have resize with window

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have the following HTML which will work to display a banner and an image. The problem is that I want the image to resize with the window. I thought that the `style="height/width"` properties would take care of this but however only width seems to work.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h3 style="text-align: center;">This company has exceeded the daily limit of Google Street Views</h3>
        <img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x600&location=40.201316987470086,-83.98099300983233" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"> </img>
    </body>
</html>
```

when clicking the bottom of the window and dragging upward, the image should resize vertically along with horizontally so that no scroll bars need to be displayed on the page.

Comment: Try adding `height:100%` to `html,body` in your CSS

Comment: have you tried using either width:100% and height:auto

Comment: To do what you're asking you'll need a more elaborate layout with a container element.

Comment: Maybe it's easier to set it as a background image and use `background-size: cover` or `background-size: contain`.

Comment: @Lal that gives me scroll bars on both the right side of the window and bottom

Comment: @Naresh217 auto causes the image to not fill the window

Comment: @isherwood can you be more specific? or provide an example where someone accomplishes this

Comment: @GolezTrol not sure how you mean to implement this I am fairly new to html

Comment: Btw there is no such thing as `</img>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it if you're willing to set a fixed height on your heading element.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: pink;
}
.wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <h3 style="text-align: center;">A Lovely Heading</h3>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/800" />
</div>
```

If you wanted the image to entirely cover the bottom area, you'll need to apply it as a background:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/800/nature);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center bottom;
}
```

```html
 <h3 style="text-align: center;">Heading</h3>
<div class="wrapper">
</div>
```

Comment: your example looks perfect on the run code snippet through stackoverflow. however if i copy/paste it into notepad++ and visit my URL then i see garbage html at the very top of the page reading as follows: "html, body { height: 100%; position: relative; } .wrapper { position: absolute; top: 80px; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0; text-align: center; background: pink; } .wrapper img { max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; }"

Comment: It's not a full web-ready document. You'll need to do a little homework for that. At a minimum, the CSS needs to be wrapped in a `style` tag.

Comment: OK, well thanks for the start this is definitely headed in the direction I;m wanting to go

Comment: @peggy you'll need to look up the basics of running a web page to make this work. If you saved this in notepad++ as a .txt file or something then it's going to open as such. If its an html file then you'll need to designate the style within a `<style> </style>` tag so that the browser knows what it's reading.

Comment: #leigero isn't this what the <html> tag is for?

Comment: @isherwood I just noticed your example still have a scroll bar on the right side of the page. It resizes correctly but I am looking for no scroll bars

Comment: Fix added. Put `overflow-hidden` on the body.

Answer (score -2):

Don't use style, the image tag as width and height built in.

```
<img src="" width="100%" height="100%">
```

Also, I don't know why you have a second closing tag here "height: 100%">>"

Comment: This alone doesn't accomplish the goal.

Comment: doesn't work. still have vertical scroll bar upon first loading the page, and a type on the second closing tag :)